# How to avoid ambiguity in constructors with default parameters?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a `class Point`, which can be constructed with rectangular  coordinates and polar coordinates. And also I want to have default parameters, which will create `Point` in coordinates (0, 0).

So, I would like to have some sort of code:

```
Class Point{
 public:
    Point(double x = 0, double y = 0); // Rectangular coordinates
    Pount(double r = 0, double a = 0); // Polar coordinates (radius and angle)
    ...
}
```

But obviously this is a bad decision, because we can't even make a call `Point()`. So as workaround we can make one of the constructors with non-default first parameter (i.e. just `int x, ...`). But what if we want to specify only x,  then we again get an error about ambiguity.

How to design such constructors correctly?

Comment: Step 1. Don't use default parameters. This is one of the many reasons why.

Comment: @CoryKramer what if the default parameters are there for a good reason?

Comment: @CoryKramer can you give some link to explanation? (to know other reasons, or maybe answer with explanation)

Comment: Why would you want 2 separate constructors for this? If the user has separate RGB values, they can trivially pass `Color(r, g, b)` for the color parameter.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley you are right! Maybe it is bad example. Lets imagine that there is no ways to do `Color(r, g, b)` :) Is it better solution, to write a some sort of convertor from one to another (becuse they have one essence) and force users to use convertor if they want Bubble from `r, g, b`

Comment: @MrPisarik: Come up with a realistic example problem, and maybe I can offer a reasonable solution.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley unfortunately it's just matter of curiosity. I haven't real example. But maybe better example in which we want to create `Point` in cartesian system and in polar system. So we will have two constructors with two double parameters and both are default.

Comment: @MrPisarik: That's a perfect example. And the solution to that is the Named Constructor Idiom. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, wow, didn't know about this. Thank you very much! I will edit question with this example.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases it makes sense to use GOF's Builder pattern.

Something like this,

```
BubbleBulder bb;
bb.setGeomtery(x, y, radius); // or separate setters for each members
bb.setColor(new Color(0, 0 ,0));
std::unique_ptr<Bubble> bubblePtr = bb.createInstance(); // or move
```